# How to iterate the loop beginning at the last element of the array and proceeding to next in a sequence? (Not reversing)

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

```
var index = -1
var array: Any [1,2,3,4,5]
for index in array {
  print(array.index)
  index += 1 
}
```

Logic : Index can minus by 1 at beginning to iterate from the last element. If i try to convery the array into indices the output is strange.

//Current output [0,1,2,3,4]
//Expected Output [5,1,2,3,4]

Comment: Your code it is not even a valid Swift syntax therefore current output wouldn't exist. Please edit your question and show your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using mapping. This solution works for any negative shift:

```
let shift = -11

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arrayLength = array.count
let index = shift % arrayLength

let indexArray = array.indices.map { $0 + index < 0 ? $0 + index + arrayLength: $0 + index}

let outputArray = indexArray.map { array[$0] }

print(outputArray)
// prints [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As evident from your example output, you simply want to print the last element first and then loop through the `array` until second last element.

You can simply do it like,

```
print(array[array.count-1])
for i in 0..<array.count-1 {
    print(array[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var index = Int()
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    let lastValue = array.last  // first get the last value in variable
    array.removeLast() // then remove your last value from array
    array.insert(lastValue!, at: 0) // then add your last value to 
    print(array)

   response = [5,1,2,3,4]
```

there is no need to right the loop

i don't know why you are doing this but with the help of some trick you can get what you want.
Thanks

```
     var index = Int()
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    let lastValue = array.last  // first get the last value in variable
    array.removeLast() // then remove your last value from array
    array.insert(lastValue!, at: 0) // then add your last value to first index in array
    for index in array {
      print(index)
    } 
index will come = [5,1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit the array, here's a quick way to do it:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let lastElement = array.popLast() // Remove and store the last item
array = [lastElement].compactMap({ $0 }) + array // Append it at the begining

print(array)
// Prints [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it all inside one for loop

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    print(array[i < 1 ? i + array.count - 1 : i - 1])
}
```

This can be written as a generic function where we can start from any position

```
func printArray<T>(_ array: [T], shift n: Int) {
    guard n >= 0 && n <= array.count else {
        return
    }
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        print(array[i < n ? i + array.count - n : i - n])
    }
}
```